# Inject CDI não esta funcionando com produtor em um projeto .jar

Tags: java, cdi

Criei um produtor de EntityManager em um projeto `.jar` mas o mesmo não funciona.

Configurei o POM.XML com a dependencia abaixo

```
<!--  CDI -->   
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>  
</dependency>
```

- Criei um arquivo beans.xml vazio em  src/main/resources/META-INF
- Criei um arquivo produtor conforme abaix

  ```
  import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
  import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
  import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
  import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
  import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
  import javax.persistence.Persistence;

  public class JpaUtil {

      private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "PEROLAWEB";

      private static ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadEntityManager = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

      private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

      @Produces 
      public EntityManager geraEM(){

          System.out.println("\n---------- injectou EntityManeger Criou ");

          if( entityManagerFactory == null || !entityManagerFactory.isOpen()) {
              entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
          }

          EntityManager entityManager = threadEntityManager.get();
          if(entityManager == null || !entityManager.isOpen() ) {
              entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
              JpaUtil.threadEntityManager.set(entityManager);
          }
          return entityManager;
      }

      public void finaliza(@Disposes EntityManager entityManager) {

          System.out.println("\n---------- destruiu EntityManeger Criou ");
          if(entityManager!=null){
              EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
              if(entityTransaction.isActive()){
                  if(entityTransaction.getRollbackOnly()) {
                      entityTransaction.rollback();
                  }else{
                      entityTransaction.commit();
                  }
              }   
              entityManager.close();
              threadEntityManager.set(null);
          }
      }

  }
  ```
- Fiz o teste abaixo mas retorna:

> java.lang.NullPointerException na linha entityManager.getTransaction().begin();**

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TesteEntityManagerFactory {

    @Inject 
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void testeDeConexao(){
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Assert.assertTrue(entityManager.getTransaction().isActive() );
    }


}
```

Comment: Quando você executa o jUnit o CDI  não é inicializado, logo os objetos não são instanciados.  Use o jGlue para testar, segue: http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/. Adiciona a dependência e segue esse tutorial de uso: http://jglue.org/cdi-unit-user-guide/.

Comment: Bem isso, Obrigado.

Comment: Blz. Coloquei uma resposta para deixar registrado e ajudar outros que tem o mesmo problema. Abraços

Comment: Veja se me ajudas.
Quanto não estou em @Test continua dando nullpointer

Comment: Você está colocando esse jar dentro de um container(wildfly, jboss, glassfish)?

Comment: Não neste momento. A ideia é criar um jar que vou utilizar em vários projetos war. Ou seja estou criando um projeto jar que o maven vai incluir num war

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41462/discussion-between-adelmo00-and-marcelo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O CDI precisa de um `container` para funcionar corretamente. Como você está executando testes com jUnit, não existe um `container` para o CDI. Para resolver isso, você pode usar o [jGlue](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/) ou o [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/). 
Se for usar o jGlue basta adicionar a seguinte dependência:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jglue.cdi-unit</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdi-unit</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

e colocar a seguinte anotação na sua classe de teste: `@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)`